# excel userform checkbox dependent on combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a UserForm in Excel where the user can select 5 types of projects, each type of project contains the list of subtypes (checkboxes).

What I'd like to do is to create a UserForm where a user can select the type of project and then the correct list of checkboxes will automatically appear in the UserForm.

For instance, if a user selects Project 1, 4 Checkboxes will appear:

`Subtype 1,Subtype 2,Subtype 3,Subtype 4`.

If he select Project 2 then 3 `checkboxes`:

`Proj Subtype 1,Proj Subtype 2, ProjSubtype 3`.

Comment: This can be done.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have managed just to create a combobox but I have no idea how to create  dependent checkboxes that will show up under the combobox after I choose the button

Comment: You'll have to put code under the `ComboBox_Change` event.  You can reference the `ComboBox.ListIndex` to get what value was selected.  Then, based on the ListIndex, you can set the checkboxes correctly.  That should hopefully be enough to get you started.  Unfortunately this isn't a "code for me" site, so you'll have to put in original effort.  If you get stuck, edit your question to show your code and we'd be glad to help.